# Why does query which subtracts the value of an unsigned int column fails in certain cases?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 2 columns `id` and `myvalue`. The `id` is primary key and the `myvalue` is an `unsigned smallint`. The current `myvalue` for `id` 1 is 0. I have the below sql query:

```
UPDATE tablename SET myvalue = IF(myvalue - 1 > 0, myvalue - 1, 0) WHERE id = 1;
```

I get the below error:

```
ERROR 1690 (22003): BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(`dbname`.`tablename`.`myvalue` - 1)'
```

Any idea why this happens? I could not find any online resources regarding this.

The same query works if I alter the table to remove unsigned from the `myvalue` column.

Answer (score 2):

If myvalue is 0, myvalue - 1 will be negative which you can't put into an unsigned integer (or it would be the unsigned integers maximum value).

This is the same check but without using myvalue - 1.

```
UPDATE tablename SET myvalue = IF(myvalue > 1, myvalue - 1, 0) WHERE id = 1;
```

Comment: It should be `myvalue > 0` or `myvalue >= 1`. Otherwise `1` will not be decremented.

Comment: I am not putting -1 into unsigned integer, that is why I have the IF condition check.

Comment: If myvalue is 0, myvalue - 1 is negative.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the filtering in the `where` clause:

```
update t
    set myvalue = myvalue - 1
    where myvalue > 0 and id = 1;
```